# Expression Engine PHP & Embed & entry_id_from

Tags: parsing, global-variables, embed, expressionengine

I have the following line in a file that is building up a PHP array and writes it in a txt file on server.:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders" entry_id_from="{embed:LAST_ID}" sort="desc" dynamic="no"}
```

AND another file that needs to take an id from database and THIS FILE must be embedded into the ACTION FILE ( the one with the line above ) and the ID to be put into the entry_id_from
LAST_ID file:

```
<?
include '!mysql.php';
$last_id = @mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT comanda_id_end FROM output_comenzi ORDER BY id DESC'),0);
if(!$last_id) $last_id = 0;
echo $last_id;
?>
```

How can I make that the `LAST_ID` file to get PARSED, take the value and insert it into `entry_id_from` file? I want to somehow embed The Parsed Mysql File into the ARRay File.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to make this work for PHP on output:**

I double checked the [EE parse order](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html) and it looks like you can make this work with EE parsing on output, but I am not 100% certain.

LAST ID File ('template_group/LAST_ID' EE template).  Set to parse PHP on output (per your requirement).

```
<?

include '!mysql.php';
$last_id = @mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT comanda_id_end FROM output_comenzi ORDER BY id DESC'),0);
if(!$last_id) $last_id = 0;

?>

// call our embedded template and pass our EE variable forward
{embed="template_group/EXPORT_ACTION_FILE" LAST_ID="<? echo  $last_id; ?>"}
```

Your other file ('template_group/EXPORT_ACTION_FILE' EE template):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders" entry_id_from="{embed:LAST_ID}" sort="desc" dynamic="no"}
```

Comment: Hey @AllInOne, the The Embed code should be in the LAST ID FILE ? How does the other file with the EXP:channel:entries know about the embed ? cheers ..  I need the Action to happen in the "OTHER FILE" ( Exp channel orders one"... i need to bring the variable to the code i believe other than code to the variable.

Comment: You posted this bit: entry_id_from="{embed:LAST_ID}" right?  embed:LAST_ID syntax implies that you are passing the variable from one EE template to another via an EE embed.  I'm assuming that the browser is requesting LAST_ID_FILE and EE is pulling in your_other_file template via embed.

Comment: I'm editing my answer to give these files names we can reference more intelligibly.

Comment: I have 2 FIles, One of it has an export php file function which is Writing a file with order info generated by EE, we call that EXPORT_ACTION_FILE and the other file is getting the last id from the database. Where should the {embed="t.... stay ? in the file with the MYSQL action ? or the other one? I need the Export_action_file to be set on OUTPUT PHP because i'm taking some of the info from EE and turning them into PHP variables and then writing them into a file , i only need EE to select the "newer Entries" and display them

Comment: Updated. Please help me make it happen, really got stuck into it. the Phh mysql file must be Input PHP , and the other one must be Output :(

Comment: Haven't solved it yet, close enoufgh thanks to AllInOne,  any news anyone?